# Form action drawing from PHP database truncates URL

Tags: php

I have created a simple form designed to open a link. The link is contained in a php database (field is 'moodle_id').

```
<form action="<?php echo $course['moodle_id']; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Enroll & Purchase Now">
```

As a link

```
<a href="<?php echo $course['moodle_id']; ?>">
```

it generates the correct `link: url.com/course/view.php?id=71`

But as a form, it generates the following: `url.com/course/view.php?`

It truncates the end of the link. Does anyone know why, or how this can be resolved?

Comment: BTW: You should add the protocol to your url (e.g. `http://url.com/course/view.php?id=71`)

Comment: The 'moodle_id' field does have the URLs formatted with http:// at the start, I just didn't type it out above. Thanks for the tip!